# Why is countplot showing single value

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I am plotting a graph but it's showing a single value in the plot.

I am currently working on a data set that has Amazone Reviews and rating. I've checked there are revies ranging from 1-5.
But the plot says it's zero.
[rating plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R63ER.png)

below is my code

```
sns.countplot(data['reviews.rating'], palette='Blues')

plt.title('Distribution of rating scores')
plt.xlabel('Rating')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Maybe you want `sns.countplot( x = data['reviews.rating'], ...)`?

Comment: thanks using `` x = `` solved the issue